# Function that returns kth smallest element

Tags: c++, loops, vector, iteration

I'm trying to write a function that returns the kth smallest element in a vector. I have to do this iteratively and cannot sort the elements. Below is what I have so far but I either get a segmentation fault or an incorrect number from the vector. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int iterative_kth_element(vector<int> &vec, size_t k){

   int cur = 0;
   int vecSmallestLocation = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
      if(vec.empty()){
         return cur;
      }
      cur = vec[0];
      for(int j=0; j<vec.size(); j++){
         if(vec[j]<cur){
            cur = vec[j];
            vecSmallestLocation = j;
         }
      }
      vec.erase(vec.begin()+(vecSmallestLocation));
   }

   cout << cur << endl;
   return cur;
}

int main(){
   vector<int> vec;
   vec.push_back(6);
   vec.push_back(21);
   vec.push_back(98);
   vec.push_back(14);
   vec.push_back(5);
   vec.push_back(7);
   vec.push_back(9);

   iterative_kth_element(vec, 3); // returns 6 but thats wrong
   //iterative_kth_element(vec, 4); // seg fault

}
```

Comment: "either get a segmentation fault or an incorrect number" what do you get for the example you posted?

Comment: nth_element partially sorts its input.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Ah..didnt see the sorting requirement.

Comment: @tobi303 this returns 6. Which is the second smallest not the third

Comment: @arunmu - It's not a requirement, it's a side effect.

Comment: @tobi303 if I pass 4 instead of 3 for example, I get a segmentation fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think the problem is that you dont initialize `vecSmallestLocation` inside the loop, it should be

```
  vecSmallestLocation = 0;             // <-- this was missing
  cur = vec[0];
  for(int j=0; j<vec.size(); j++){
     if(vec[j]<cur){
        cur = vec[j];
        vecSmallestLocation = j;
     }
  }
  vec.erase(vec.begin()+(vecSmallestLocation));
```

because if the first element is the smallest your `if` will not set the correct value for the index to be removed (as `vec[0] < cur` is false if `cur == vec[0]`) but the one from the last iteration is used (possibly causing a seg fault if this is beyond the vectors size)

Actually I would suggest you to use the limits from `std::limits`, because at the moment your function only works when all the vector elements are >0.

PS: There are std algorithms to do what you want, but often enough one has to do it manually, for this reason I usually use something like this

```
struct MinValueAndIndex {
   int index;
   int value;
   MinValueAndIndex(const std::vector<int>& v) 
        : index(0), value(v[0]) {}
};
```

to avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

An edge case may be giving the segmentation fault. 
You carry over the variable `vecSmallestLocation` because it is out the scope of the loop. Therefore, look at the if statement in the loop:

```
     if(vec[j]<cur){
        cur = vec[j];
        vecSmallestLocation = j;
     }
```

If it is the case, that no variables remaining in the vector have a value less than `cur` this `if` statement never gets entered, and `vecSmallestLocation`never gets correctly assigned to a new value. 
When you enter the loop, after deleting 5, 6 is the smallest value and `vecSmallestLocation` will not be updated, still retaining the value of the last iterations global minimum, which was `vec[4]`. Therefore, you erroneously delete the element at position `vec[4]` again, which is 7. This is wrong.

Try `if(vec[j] <= cur)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes what tobi pointed is correct, you have to initialise vecSmallestLocation outside the inner loop. And as far as segmentation fault considered it is occurring because you are passing the vector by reference and your function is modifying the vector and reducing its size to 3 and there is no 4th smallest element in your new vector. So do not pass the vector by reference.

Below is the modified version of your code. I tried to modify it as minimum as possible.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void iterative_kth_element(vector<int> vec, size_t k)
{
   int cur = 0;
   int vecSmallestLocation = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
   {
      if(vec.empty())
      {
         return ;
      }
      cur = vec[0];
      vecSmallestLocation = 0;
      for(int j=0; j<vec.size(); j++)
      {
         if(vec[j]<cur)
         {
            cur = vec[j];
            vecSmallestLocation = j;
         }
      }
      vec.erase(vec.begin()+(vecSmallestLocation));
   }
   cout << cur << endl;
}

int main(){
   vector<int> vec;
   vec.push_back(6);
   vec.push_back(21);
   vec.push_back(98);
   vec.push_back(14);
   vec.push_back(5);
   vec.push_back(7);
   vec.push_back(9);

   iterative_kth_element(vec, 3); 
   iterative_kth_element(vec, 4); 
}
```

Comment: "So do not pass the vector by reference."  Or better yet, pass by a const reference and don't modify the vector.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you could do this without having to scan the whole vector for each successive number (unless you keep tabs on something like the next smallest number to the left and its location, so you only have to scan everything to the right for each next read).  You'd also have to deal with the special case where two numbers are identical.  Remember that the algorithm is fully iterative (even when recursive), meaning that each successive item depends on knowledge of the previous, unless you sort.  Remember to break it down into simpler problems.

You also really don't need to modify the vector to do this.  I'm not sure why you're running an erase in there, based on your description.

- How do you find the first smallest number?

  - Scan the list for the leftmost smallest number
- How do you find the next smallest number?

  - Scan the list for the next number identical to the last one but with a greater index, or if no other identical number exists, give the next larger number (this is important to avoid identical numbers that have already been returned)
- How do you find the `i`th smallest number?

  - Repeat the algorithm, and keep count.

Break down the routines into independent, easy-to-understand parts.

So, something like this (I avoided iterators so that I could work primarily on indicies.  In my own code, I'd genericize them all to templates that work only on iterators, or make a special iterator-type that does this, so that I could fully iterate in order.  Also note that this code does not handle edge cases, like an empty vector or you specifying a value for k larger than the size of the vector):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

// Get the index of the smallest value
vector<int>::size_type get_smallest_index(const vector<int> &vec)
{
    vector<int>::size_type index = 0;
    int smallest = vec.front();
    for (vector<int>::size_type i = 1; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (vec[i] < smallest)
        {
            index = i;
            smallest = vec[i];
        }
    }
    return index;
}

// Get the index of the next smallest value
vector<int>::size_type get_smallest_index(const vector<int> &vec, const vector<int>::size_type prev_index)
{
    vector<int>::size_type next = prev_index;
    int next_value = 0;
    for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        // If there is another value identical to the last but further along
        if (i > prev_index && vec[i] == vec[prev_index])
        {
            return i;
        }
        // If the value is greater than the previous, and either the next hasn't been set or it is less than the existing next value
        if (vec[i] > vec[prev_index] && (next == prev_index || vec[i] < next_value))
        {
            next = i;
            next_value = vec[i];
        }
    }
    return next;
}
int iterative_kth_element(vector<int> &vec, size_t k)
{
    // Get the smallest index to start with
    vector<int>::size_type index = get_smallest_index(vec);

    // Get the next smallest index * k (so it's 0-indexed)
    for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        index = get_smallest_index(vec, index);
    }

    return vec[index];
}

int main(){
   vector<int> vec;
   vec.push_back(6);
   vec.push_back(21);
   vec.push_back(98);
   vec.push_back(14);
   vec.push_back(5);
   vec.push_back(7);
   vec.push_back(9);

   assert(iterative_kth_element(vec, 3) == 9);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finding kth smallest should not be changing your initial vector, because you are destroying information. You can update the function as follows.

```
int iterative_kth_element(const vector<int> &vec, size_t k){
   // You only need to check this once now
   // and do a double check to make sure that kth element is valid
   if(vec.empty() && vec.size() <= k){
      // return INT_MAX and not 0  because the smallest element could possible be 0
      return numeric_limits<int>::min();
   }
   int cur = numeric_limits<int>::max();
   int lastMin = numeric_limits<int>::min();
   for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<vec.size(); j++){
         if(vec[j] >= lastMin && vec[j] < cur){
            cur = vec[j];
         }
      }
      lastMin = cur;
      cur = numeric_limits<int>::max();
   }
   cout << lastMin << endl;
   return lastMin;
}
```

This method, firstly doesn't destroy information in your vector by deleting it. Secondly the time complexity of this algorithm is same as yours, which is O(kn) where n is vec.size(). And lastly will run without errors and give you the kth smallest element.

Comment: Did you maybe forget to `#include <climits>`? Why using c headers when there is `numeric_limits<int>::max` in `<limits>` ? Why does you function still take a non-const parameter? And last but not least, did you actually test your code? It only returns the smallest element (but to do this you traverse the vector k times).

Comment: @tobi303  You were correct and that has been fixed.

Comment: It is still kind of wrong. If the vector contains 1 3 3 3 4 your algorithm will return 4 as the 3rd smallest element, because you only check if the new next smallest element is bigger than the last one. Of course it can make sense to look for the k smallest value (as opposed to k smallest element) but I dont think that is what OP wants, otherwise he should have used a `std::set` instead of a `vector`